# How to determine if a user is an admin or not within a forensic image?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

When working from a forensic image of a PC, and *without* virtualizing the image, is there a way to determine whether a particular user is an Admin?

If so, is there also a way to tell when they were granted Admin rights?

Comment: I prefer the Slap Chop....lol.

Answer (score 1):

> without virtualizing the image, is there a way to determine whether a particular user is an Admin?

Read group membership from the Registry, specifically from the `SAM` file. Can't name any Windows tools for this right now, but Linux has `chntpw` which can be used to show what groups a user is in. (Well, Regedit could work, but it's a bit more difficult as the groups are stored in binary format.)

> If so, is there a way to tell when they were granted Admin rights?

Read the Event Log – the *Security.evtx* log might contain auditing events that record changes to local group memberships.

This assumes all users are local. In case the local Administrators group had a domain group added as member, the PC wouldn't know anything about indirect changes to that domain  group until the moment the user tried to log in.

Answer (score 1):

There are many forensics products that can analyze many aspects of the
system image. However, most are commercial and very costly.

For analyzing the information about user accounts, you need only
two registry hives: SAM and SYSTEM.

Some free products that can analyze these hives are:

- [ArtiFast Lite](https://www.forensafe.com/free.html)
- [SAMInside](https://softradar.com/saminside/)
- [RegRipper](https://github.com/keydet89/RegRipper3.0)

Some of the tools were actually designed to rip passwords, but can also
serve for forensics.

For more information see:

- [Using the SAM hive to profile user accounts](https://hatsoffsecurity.com/2014/05/21/using-the-sam-hive-to-profile-user-accounts/)
- [7 best computer forensics tools [updated 2021]](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/7-best-computer-forensics-tools/)